# Getting Azure Function App log output to Log Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-functions

We are using and Azure Functions in a larger chain of events. All other parts of this chain have their logs available in log analytics so that we can easily trace any given request through the entire system. However, I can't find a way to get the Function App logs to the same place. I'm guessing it should be possible since it looks like this in our workspace:

[image: logs workspace]

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring) for monitoring function apps only mention Application Insights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55239531/error-setting-up-azure-function-within-azure-resource-under-log-analytics-worksp) I answered before.

In short, Log analytics does not support Azure function very well, and that's why it recommends application insights in those docs.

You can go to the azure portal -> your log analytics -> in the left blade, select Workspace Data Sources -> Azure Resources, then click your azure function there. Screenshot as below:

[image]

But when you select the items under `LOG CATEGORY`, it will throw an error. And it's a known issue(I asked the MS team before and the feedback is that it's a issue and maybe will not update on this).

[image]

And if you just want to query logs(azure function logs) from app insights within log analytics, you can use cross query operator [app()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/app-expression).

Comment: So basically there is no way to aggregate logs in a single space for solutions deployed in Azure? That's too bad, I'll work around it some other way. Application Insights is not a substitute  for log analytics, seems like a weird choice by them.

Comment: Actually, it's very convenient to query logs from app insights. In log analytics, just use [app()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/app-expression) operator. Hope it can help you. And if it is helpful, could you please help mark it as answer? Thanks :).

Comment: The app operator was new to me and very helpful, thank you!